# How add/fetch data from firestore using StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add data in my firestore like

->users(collection)->userid(document)->friends(collection)

**I want to add/fetch data from friends collection**

Here is my code:

```
 Future<void> _getUserDoc() async {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;

    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    DocumentReference ref = _firestore.collection('users').document(user.uid);
 }


Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document()
        .collection('friends')
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData)
        return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        ));

      return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
    },
  );
}
```

**In the widget _buildbody how i use user.uid to fetch the data in friends collection.**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your widget is a stateful widget, then you can have user doc reference in state of widget and use same ref for fetching friends collection data like:

```
 DocumentReference userRef;
 @override
 initState(){ 
  super.initState();
  _getUserDoc();
 } 

 //Call this method from initState()
 Future<void> _getUserDoc() async {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;

    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    setState((){
      userRef = _firestore.collection('users').document(user.uid);
    });
 }


Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
  if(userRef == null) {
  CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        ));
  }

  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: userRef
        .collection('friends')
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData)
        return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        ));

      return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
    },
  );
}
```

P.S. : Just make sure, userRef is not null before calling StreamBuilder function "_buildBody"

Comment: In the getuserDoc(), userRef shows error - Undefined name 'userRef'.dart(undefined_identifier)

Comment: class _FirstLeaderState extends State<FirstLeader> {
  DocumentReference userRef;
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUserDoc();
  }

Comment: Oh..did you tried hot restart instead of hot reload. I mean if you are running from terminal try entering "R" instead of "r" to reload the app. As widgets if already built, adding new state variables wont be recognised as state method was already called and wont be called for hot reload, Can you please confirm if error exists even with Hot Restart. Thank you.

Comment: I rebuild the app. And the error on the screen is -> NoSuchMethodError  : The method 'collection' was on null. Receiver : null. Tried calling: collection()

Comment: Yes, As I mentioned in my P.S. comment, check "userRef" is not null before building streamBuilder. :). Try returning CircularProgressIndicator at the begining of the method "_buildBody" till userRef is null, also I missed one thing, userRef = _firestore.collection('users').document(user.uid);
 inside setState call, I will make corrections in my suggestion to help you better undertand

Comment: A new error on screen - type '_OneByteString' is not a subtype of type 'int'.

Comment: Which part of your code is throwing this error. Try casting data you have in snapshots in correct type before using in widgets. You can also try printing all data you have in snapshot.data just to be sure what data is present

Comment: Here is complete code - https://github.com/pyclasses/Happy-Birthday-Sister/blob/master/my.dart

Comment: Please post all code on Stackoverflow only, also if possible put error log which is shown on your console. As per error you are getting my guess could be because snapshot may not be having votes entry stored as dart int, try changing following line from Record=>fromSnapshot method to "votes = int.tryParse(map['votes'])?? 0;"

Comment: No issue, as I said, if you could provide logs we can locate exact code line which is causing the issue, also did you check what data is getting passed into "fromMap" method, just try printing "map" variable passed to the method, to be sure what data is present in the map variable when you pass the data. Also what flutter & dart version you are using. can you provide "flutter doctor" log too?

Comment: Everything is fine when I debug the app. But not showing the data in friends collection. And In release mode red error screen is present. OneByteString (mentioned above)

Comment: Oh, thats weird, try posting new question with this new issue, may be someone who has faced same issue might be able to help you out.

Comment: Hey @Ganapat, Here is my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54850349/how-fetch-data-from-firestore-using-streambuilderquerysnapshot-in-flutter

Comment: That's Awesome! :)